# How to make a page without header and footer in WordPress and load The event calendar's single event as a popup

Tags: wordpress

Two questions together

1. How to make a page without header and footer in WordPress and
2. Load The Event Calendar plugin's single event post as a popup on that page

## TheEventCalendar Link - https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/

Comment: You can create a page template and within that template remove the functions that call the header and footer functions.  Start by reading this https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Calender Page
 * If it is saprate page then you can define template name and use it with page OR if it is post single page then save as single-your-post-slug.php
 */
?>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    
                the_content();
            endwhile;
        ?>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page template that displays only the content of your page without header and footer.
Ex :

```
<?php /* Template Name: Event calendar popup */
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

Put this file in your theme folder.
Then create a page and give it this template. Add the shortcode in the editor.